# two random variables with the same distributions are linked through a measure preserving transformation?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

The title says it all.

Given two measurable functions $f:X\to \mathbb C$ and $g:Y\to \mathbb C$, where $(X,\mu)$ and $(Y,\nu)$ are two probability spaces, suppose they have the same distributions.

Is it true that there exists a measure-preserving measurable function $\phi:X\to Y$

$\nu(\phi(U)) = \mu(U)$ and $\mu(\phi^{-1}(V)) = \nu(V)$

such that $f = g \circ \phi$ almost everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have stated it, it's a tiny bit delicate.  It holds if $X$ and $Y$ are [standard probability spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_probability_space#Measure_preserving_transformations).  If you talk about the induced measures  on  $\mathbb C$   given by $\mu'(A)=\mu(f^{-1}(A))$ and $\nu'=\nu(g^{-1}(A))$ for $A\subset\mathbb C,$ the answer is yes.  (Because $\mathbb C$ is a standard probability space.)

Comment: $f,g$ have the same distribution if and only if $\mu'=\nu'$ as you've defined them. The question is exactly as I have stated it.
Do you have any reference for this result?

Comment: The wikipedia article I cited has references.  I  know very little about non-standard probability spaces.

Comment: A bit convoluted, but I guess it goes like this: Let $F(U) := f^{-1}\circ g(U)$. By definition, it should be an homomorphism of measure algebras between $Y$ and $X$, so if they are standard probability space, there is $\varphi:X\to Y$ such that $F(U) = \varphi^{-1}(U)$ and all that's missing to prove is $f=g\circ \varphi$. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, I think so.